# get top 3 random values from sql query

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have written this query on oracle

```
SELECT itemcode,itemname from hmis.shopitemcode order by dbms_random.value
```

Its working fine and I got random record but my question is I just want only 5 random record not all the record from database table

when I try to use this query

```
SELECT itemcode,itemname from hmis.shopitemcode where ROWNUM <= 5 order by dbms_random.value
```

this query randomize top 5 record not get 5 random record from whole database table

Comment: may be try using rownum, in a outer query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hope this helps!

```
select * from (
   SELECT itemcode,itemname from hmis.shopitemcode order by dbms_random.value
)
where rownum <= 5;
```